# Draw circles and compute <sum of circle areas>-<area of overlaps of the circles>

Tags: computational-geometry

The following code draws the polygons of `VoronoiMesh[pts]`:

```
SeedRandom[3]; 
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];
vertices = MeshCoordinates[mesh];
Show[mesh, Graphics[{Black, Point[pts], Red, Point[vertices]}]]
```

The output is:

[image]

The black points are `pts`, the red ones the vertices of the Voronoi mesh.

#### My questions:

- How can I draw circles around each point in `pts` with a given radius $r$, such as $0.18$?
- How can I compute `<sum of circle areas>-<area of overlaps of the circles>`, i.e.
  $$\left(\sum_{c\in\mathrm{Circles}}\mathrm{Area}(c)\right)-\left(\sum_{o\in\mathrm{Overlaps}}\mathrm{Area}(o)\right)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure are you interested in the union of the disks or the union sans the intersections. The code below can be used for both cases.

### Implicit regions

```
r = 0.18;
regs = ImplicitRegion[
     Sqrt[(x - #[[1]])^2 + (y - #[[2]])^2] <= r, {x, y}] & /@ pts;
```

### Circles drawing

```
Show[mesh, 
 Graphics[{Cyan, Circle[#, r] & /@ pts, Black, Point[pts], Red, 
   Point[vertices]}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

### Union

```
c = Ceiling[Max[pts] + r, 0.5];

AbsoluteTiming[
 dregs = DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[regs], {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium]
 ]
```

[image]

```
RegionMeasure[dregs]

(* 1.99653 *)
```

### Union \ Intersection

```
ires = DeleteCases[
   Flatten[Table[
     RegionIntersection[regs[[i]], regs[[j]]], {i, 1, 
      Length[regs]}, {j, i + 1, Length[regs]}]], _EmptyRegion];

AbsoluteTiming[
 dires = DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[ires], {{-c, c}, {-c, c}}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-c, c}, {-c, c}}]
 ]
```

[image]

```
RegionMeasure[dregs] - RegionMeasure[dires]

(* 1.56288 *)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. But, I want to draw circle around each pts point, which is represented by black points and keeps also the voronoi diagram. Then, detect the overlapping areas occurs between these circles. Then calculate the sum of these circles' areas subtracted by the overlapping areas. I think, there is a difference between the circle and the disk.

Comment: @Eman See my edit. It should be close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and your edit. I really appreciate that. Your edit is what I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Comment: Excuse me, If I want to make **only 15 circles** with **radius of 0.18** and the **other 10 circles** with **radius of 0.25**,then compute `<sum of circle areas>-<area of overlaps of the circles>` , what should I modify in your code to do that??

Comment: @Eman You can have a separate list of radiuses and use `MapThread` when making the implicit regions. E.g. `regs = MapThread[
  ImplicitRegion[
    Sqrt[(x - #1[[1]])^2 + (y - #1[[2]])^2] <= #2, {x, y}] &, {pts, 
   rs}]` .

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. it worked. But, please, I want to make sure of some thing if you don't mind. I noticed that; when I calculated the **area of the 25 circles** using `25*pi*(0.18^2)`, It gave the output of `0.254469` and the `RegionMeasure[dregs]` in your code, gave the output of `1.99653`. I suppose that, `RegionMeasure` gave the area of the region. So, in case of `RegionMeasure[dregs]`, it should give the area of the 25 circles, which should be `0.254469`. Why does it give different value??

Answer (score 5):

```
radius = .18;
disks = Disk[#, radius] & /@ pts;
25 Area[disks[[1]]]
```

> 2.54469

```
Area[RegionUnion[disks]]
```

> 2.03381

```
Show[mesh, Graphics[{Black, Point[pts], Red, Point[vertices], 
  FaceForm[Opacity[.5,LightGreen]],EdgeForm[{Thick,Darker@Green}], disks}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @eman, my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is much better to use [`RegionMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure) on the undiscretized regions. For instance:

```
disks = Disk[#, .18]& /@ pts;

ru = RegionMeasure @ RegionUnion[disks]
RegionMeasure @ DiscretizeRegion @ RegionUnion[disks]
```

> 2.03381
>
> 1.99723

The region measure of the discretized version is almost 2% off. Similarly:

```
ires = DeleteCases[
    Flatten @ Table[
        RegionIntersection[disks[[i]], disks[[j]]],
        {i, 1, 25},
        {j, i + 1, 25}
    ],
    _EmptyRegion
];

int = RegionMeasure @ RegionUnion @ ires
RegionMeasure @ DiscretizeRegion @ RegionUnion @ ires
```

> 0.44757
>
> 0.439748

So a more accurate answer would be:

```
ru - int
```

> 1.58624

Finally, it is possible to get this result directly by using [`BooleanCountingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanCountingFunction):

```
RegionMeasure @ BooleanRegion[
    BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, 25],
    disks
]
```

> 1.58624

although this version is slower than Antons.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.